# Need information from a javascript function within the html

Tags: javascript, html, image, variables

I'm trying to retrieve images from a local file by appending .jpg to a string. The web pages is a dictionary so I take the current available word from a different location in the html. Is there anyway to then output a link to the image from the javascript? This is what I have tried so far.

JavaScript:

```
function getImage () {
        x = document.getElementById("word").innerHTML;
        image = "images/" + x + ".jpg";
        return image; 
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img id="circle" src="getImage()" alt="image">
</div>
```

I'm retrieving "word" with an xmlhttprequest that ends like this

```
var item = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("word")[i].childNodes[0];
document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = item.nodeValue;
```

Comment: Please learn how to use js in html. src="getImage()" this is not valid

Comment: Can you update the question to provide an example of the HTML which provides #word?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<div>
    <img id="circle" alt="image">
</div>

<script>
    var imageName = document.getElementById("word").innerHTML;
    var imagePath = "images/" + name + ".jpg";
    document.getElementById('circle').src = imagePath;
</script>
```

The issue with your code is that you tried to run that function from within the `src` attribute of the image tag, but that's not how that works. You need to run your JavaScript code and then explicitly set the `src` attribute.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work although it seems like it should. I'm not getting any errors in the console.